# How to override twillio sdk base url

Tags: kotlin, twilio, twilio-api, wiremock

I am writing integration tests for twilio using wiremock in kotlin. Any suggestions how to mock it (change base url of client). I am using init method to initialise client but it do not provide anything to override baseurl.

```
import com.twilio.Twilio
import com.twilio.http.TwilioRestClient

class CustomTwilioClient(accountSid: String, authToken: String, baseUrl: String) : TwilioRestClient(accountSid, authToken) {
    init {
        this.baseUri = baseUrl
    }

val customTwilioClient = CustomTwilioClient("your_account_sid", "your_auth_token", "http://localhost:8080/2010-04-01")
Twilio.init(customTwilioClient)
```

I have tried above snippet but its throwing error Unresolved reference: baseUri

Comment: The baseUri property is not part of the public API and therefore cannot be easily overridden.

Answer (score 1):

For testing, I'd recommend using the [Test Credentials](https://www.twilio.com/docs/iam/test-credentials) instead of modifying the base URL.

> You use these credentials in the same way as your live credentials, with one restriction being that you cannot login to the Twilio CLI with your test credentials. However, when you authenticate with your test credentials, **we will not charge your account, update the state of your account, or connect to real phone numbers**. You can now pretend to buy a phone number, or send an SMS, without actually doing so.
>
> To protect your production data, your test credentials can't interact with the data in your real account. For example, you can't use phone numbers from your real account as the 'From' number in requests made with your test credentials.